The GNS represenation for a Von neumann algebra is a Von neumann algebra.
Let $M$ be a Von Neumann algebra and $\omega$ be a faithful $\sigma$-weakly continuous positive tracial state on $M$. I know that we have an inner product space on $M$ because $\omega$ is faithful. Given a GNS pair $(H_\omega, \xi_\omega, \pi_\omega)$ on $M$(there exists one namely $\xi := I$ and $\pi(x)y := xy$), then I am a bit confused why $\omega$ being $\sigma$-weakly continuous implies that $\pi_\omega$ is? I know that $\pi_\omega$ is isometric so $\pi_\omega(M_1) = (\pi_\omega(M))_1$. I know from Kaplansky that $M_1$ is $\sigma$ weakly closed, so it's $\sigma$-weak operator compact because the unit ball is $\sigma$-weak operator compact due to Alaoglu. Hence, $(\pi_\omega(M))_1$ is $\sigma$-weak operator compact since $\pi_\omega$ is $\sigma$-weakly continuous. I never really knew this, but is the operator topologies Hausdorff? If they are Hausdorff, then $(\pi_\omega(M))_1$ is $\sigma$-weak operator closed. I know that unital self adjoint subalgebra's $A$ unit ball $A_1$  is weak operator closed implies that $A$ is weak operator closed(which implies its a von neumann algebra), but what would be the proof for this? If I show this, then $\pi(M)$ is a von neumann algebra.

Your question is a bit garbled. Just to clarify, you need a proof of the following facts: 1. If $\omega$ is $\sigma$-weakly continuous, then so is $\pi_\omega$. 2. The operator topologies are Hausdorff. 3. $A_1$ is $\sigma$-weakly closed implies $A$ is $\sigma$-weakly closed. Is this correct?

@DavidGao I don't need the complete proofs. I tried showing that $\pi_\omega$ is $\sigma$-weak operator(not the weak operator one rather the one defined from trace class operators) continuous using $\omega(x) = \langle \pi_\omega(x) \xi_\omega, \xi_\omega \rangle$, but I am having issues with that. Actually I think I figured out that operator topologies are hausdorff since I can show that the semi norms are separating easily. I would appreciate some guidance in 3 since I know the reverse you use Kaplansky density theorem. However in the notes I am reading, the author says 3 is straightforward.

wait actually, for the hausdorff one. If I pick distinct bounded operators $x$ and $y$, then there exists $\eta \in H$ such that $x \eta \neq y \eta$ but that does not guarantee that $||x \eta|| \neq ||y \eta||$( I am using strong operator topology as an example)

Well, it could be the case that $|x\eta| = |y\eta|$ for all $\eta$. For example, if both $x$ and $y$ are isometries, then $|x\eta| = |\eta| = |y\eta|$ for all $\eta$. But to prove the seminorms are separating, you only need $|(x-y)\eta| \neq 0$, which would be the case as long as $x\eta \neq y\eta$.

For 3, it is the direction that $A_1$ being $\sigma$-weakly closed implies $A$ being $\sigma$-weakly closed that requires Kaplansky density. The converse is straightforward. I’m not sure what the author of the notes means in saying 3 is straightforward. As far as I can tell, Kaplansky density is necessary.

For 1, hint: you can approximate trace-class operators by finite-rank operators, and vectors in $H_\omega$ can be approximated by vectors in $\pi_\omega(M) \xi_\omega$.

@DavidGao Oh I figured out 3. Both ways use Kaplansky(the reverse is super immediate like you were mentioning).I showed that if $A_1$ is weakly closed, then $A$ is weakly closed(when $A$ is a unital self adjoint sub algebra) by using $x/||x||$. For the $\sigma$ weak closedness, I remember reading somewhere that on the unit ball we have a homeomorphism between $\sigma$ weak operator topology and weak operator topology. I think this fact is true, was it the identity map and I would just need to show that it's a homeomorphism?

The converse of 3 doesn’t even need Kaplansky. It’s just $B(H)_1$ is $\sigma$-weakly closed and so $A_1 = A \cap B(H)_1$ is $\sigma$-weakly closed, being the intersection of two closed sets.

Yeah. The identity map is a homeomorphism. It’s continuous from a compact space to a Hausdorff space, so a homeomorphism.
